# Streaming updates to Stack Overflow questions

Tags: discussion, notifications, api, comment-replies, screen-scraping

I would like to find a better way to be notified when someone replies to a comment or question I post on Stack Overflow. Right now, I have to go through a few pages to figure out where I wrote, and if anything of mine was updated.  And the "recent" tab only goes so far...

Is it legal to run a crawler on the site to get that info?  Or is there an API for getting that info yet?

How do you manage this stuff right now, those of you who are answering millions of questions?

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API released as of yet (although if I am understanding correctly, it is in development. Expect it in 6 to 8 weeks).

I don't think it is ILLEGAL to run a crawler over the site, but you run the risk of getting IP banned if you start to use up a lot of resources (this happened in the past).

One method that you could keep on top of things is by using the RSS feeds which are available for Questions, Users, Tags. Just about anything you could need.

Comment: Thanks, the rss feeds aren't all working yet it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's one of the most needed things in here.

Personally, the only way I've found of keeping track is to put the questions you're interested in, in your bookmarks (S-3 active question), and revisit them from time to time. Primitive, ...